# Find the original strings from the results of str_extract_all

Tags: r, stringr

I'm still young to coding and cannot figure out better functions or results to some tasks by myself very often.
I have a question on tracking the original string after using `str_extract_all` for a specific pattern.

Here is an example data called "fruit".

| index | Fruit |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple |
| 2 | banana |
| 3 | strawberry |
| 4 | pineapple |
| 5 | bell pepper |

I used `str_extract_all(fruit, "(.)\\1")` to extract duplicated consonants, and get "pp", "rr", "pp", "ll", "pp".

Also tracked the original string (of those extracted results) by `str_subset(fruit, "(.)\\1")`. Here's what I get.

| index | fruit |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple |
| 2 | strawberry |
| 3 | pineapple |
| 4 | bell pepper |

However, I want to know where "each" extracted result is from. Therefore, using `str_subset` cannot capture those results which are from the same string. The following dataframe is what I expect to gain.

| index | fruit | pattern |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | pp |
| 2 | strawberry | rr |
| 3 | pineapple | pp |
| 4 | bell pepper | ll |
| 4 | bell pepper | pp |

I'm not sure if I explain my question clearly. Any feedbacks and ideas will be appreciate.

Comment: Do you just want `df$pattern <- stringr::str_extract(df$xfruit "(.)\\1")` and then `df <- df[!is.na(df$pattern),]`? See https://ideone.com/kB9FpD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code already did what you want. You just need to create an extra column to store the output of `str_extract_all`, like the following:

Since `str_extract_all()` returns a list, we'll need to `unnest` the list to become rows.

The final line of the code is to create a consecutive index (since "banana" is gone, index 2 will also be gone).

```
library(tidyverse)

fruit %>% 
  mutate(pattern = str_extract_all(Fruit, "(.)\\1")) %>% 
  unnest(pattern) %>%
  mutate(index = as.numeric(as.factor(index)))

# A tibble: 5 × 3
  index Fruit       pattern
  <dbl> <chr>       <chr>  
1     1 apple       pp     
2     2 strawberry  rr     
3     3 pineapple   pp     
4     4 bell pepper ll     
5     4 bell pepper pp
```

Comment: Hi @benson23. It's very clear, and my problem solved. Thank you so much!